# find a substring pattern followed by one substring but not by another substring

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have hospital data (opcs, NHS) which comprises of procedure codes followed by a code to indicate laterality.

Using `Regex` and `R`, I would like to identify a procedure code in a string which is followed other procedure codes then the laterality code.

However the match must not include procedure codes of intrest, which are followed by a different laterality code. Example:

```
string <- ("W100 Z923 W200 A456 W200 B234 A234 Z921")
```

What I am trying to match:`"W100|W200"`

What it must be followed by: `"Z921"`
e.g. Should match this `W200 B234 A234 Z921`

But must not be followed by: `"Z922|Z923"`
e.g. Should not match this `W100 Z923 W200 A456 W200 B234 A234 Z921`

What I have tried:

```
#match the procedure follow by Z921: 
(W100|W200).{1,}?Z941 

# I do not know how to add a negative look back to exclude matches without stopping this working, I have tried this, but it fails:
((W100|W200).{1,}Z941) (?<!Z943|Z942)
```

edit: Improved the clarity of question and reprex

Comment: Do you mean the `Z943` and `Z942` should not appear between the two strings? Like `\bW[12]00\b(?:(?!\bZ92[23]\b).)*?\bZ941\b`? See https://regex101.com/r/e7W9KR/2

Comment: Thanks. Yes `Z943` and `Z942` should not appear between the matched `W100|W200` and the laterality code `Z941`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "\\bW[12]00\\b(?!\\s+Z92[23]\\b).*?Z941")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yv1rHa/2). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `W[12]00` - `W100` or `W200`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\s+Z92[23]\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more whitespaces and then `Z923` or `Z922` as a whole word
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `Z941` - a `Z941` string.

Comment: My question was not clear, apologies. I have updated the quesiton to make it clearer

Comment: @JisL Please test your strings at https://regex101.com/r/yv1rHa/1 and let know if it works or not. If not, share the test link

Comment: Thank you, this works after editing the code slightly. I cannot seem to edit your answer to reflect this: https://regex101.com/r/yv1rHa/2. `\bW[12]00\b(?!\s+Z92[23]\b).*?Z941`

Comment: Ok, so no whole word checking is necessary at the end, I see.

Comment: Thanks again, the final `regex` which works is `\bW[12]00\b(?!\s+Z94[23]\b).*?Z941`